# how to set http header before custom handler on apache 2.2

Tags: apache, cookies, http-headers, http-referer

I have a custom module in apache 2.2 that check the referrer header and decide if drop the request or perform process for the answer. 
Apache is under cloudfront cdn so no header like user-agent and referrer is forwarded.

The solution would be add a cookie in the request with referrer and from apache side take that and use that to overwrite referrer header. Is this possible?

Summarizing i would take custom value in the cookie and put it in the referrer header and process it in our custom module.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RequestReadTimeout header=10-30,MinRate=500
    RewriteEngine On
    Header set Referer HTTP_COOKIE:referer 
    RequestHeader unset Authorization
    <Location /getobject>
            SetHandler getobject
    </Location>
```

I tested with debug tool on browser and i'm sure that cookie is sent to the server.
I tried with the example above but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer to myself 
i can add headers i need on the server via javascript in the cookies

```
document.cookie="referrer="+window.parent.location;
```

after that on the server i can use

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Cookie ^ $ "( referrer = \ w *: \ / \ / \ w *)" HTTP_MY_COOKIE = $ 1
SetEnvIfNoCase HTTP_MY_COOKIE " (http : \ / \ / . * \ . \ w *)" Referrer = $ 1 
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  RequestHeader % { Referer } and Referrer
</IfModule >
```